# Django TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, django

I'm following a Django tutorial and suddenly when I try to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ it gives me a TemplateSyntaxError.

TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/

Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Tried results in module polls.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'results'

It highlights this line:
{% url 'django-admindocs-docroot' as docsroot %}

The admin page worked like a charm until I got to part 3 of the tutorial and messed with the urls, although I did it exactly like they said so I doubt it's the problem.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^polls/$', 'polls.views.index'),
    (r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'polls.views.detail'),
    (r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'polls.views.results'),
    (r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'polls.views.vote'),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

admin.py:

```
from polls.models import Poll
from polls.models import Choice
from django.contrib import admin

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 0

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['question']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
    list_display = ('question', 'pub_date')
    list_filter = ['pub_date']
    search_fields = ['question']
    date_hierarchy = 'pub_date'

admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from polls.models import Poll
from django.template import Context, loader

def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    t = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    c = Context({
        'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

def detail(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at poll %s. " % poll_id)

def vote(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on poll %s." % poll_id)
```

Comment: post you poll/views.py file. That seems to be where the error is

Comment: I added def results to views.py and it worked, but why? Can't django just ignore it? Some things in django sometimes just don't make sense.

Comment: um, it makes perfect sense. When someone visits the URL /polls/1234/results/ the function "results" gets called from your views.py and the argument id is passed to it. That function then renders your template and returns it to the user. It's how Django works

Comment: But I'm not visiting results.

Comment: You told django that the view exists when you put it in your URLs.py. When someone checks a webpage, Django checks all your URLs, therefore it looks for that view (which you haven't created)

Comment: But if I don't even need it and it's just checking, why does it cancel out the entire page?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Tried results in module polls.views. 
Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'results'
```

That's pretty much all you need. Ignore the `TemplateSyntaxError`, it's not related to the template at all. Django is telling you that you don't have this:

```
def results(request):
    # do something
```

In your views.py. You'll get `ViewDoesNotExist` errors outside the admin when you start writing urls and referencing functions that don't actually exist in them, so make sure as you progress that you either ensure you have such stub functions that just return a basic 200, or you comment out those urls until you need them.

Technically speaking this is an extension of a python error. If you ran:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from poll import views
x = views.results
```

You'd get an [`AttributeError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.AttributeError).

Since you asked why, if you look in `Django/core/urlresolvers.py` you'll see the line:

```
_callable_cache = {} # Maps view and url pattern names to their view functions.
```

So basically a cache of view mappings (urls or whatever) to functions is made in the form of a hashmap (dictionary). This is constructed by this function:

```
def _get_callback(self):
    if self._callback is not None:
        return self._callback
    try:
        self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
    except ImportError, e:
        mod_name, _ = get_mod_func(self._callback_str)
        raise ViewDoesNotExist("Could not import %s. Error was: %s" % (
                                                            mod_name, str(e)))
    except AttributeError, e:
        mod_name, func_name = get_mod_func(self._callback_str)
        raise ViewDoesNotExist("Tried %s in module %s. Error was: %s" % (
                                                   func_name, mod_name, str(e)))
    return self._callback
callback = property(_get_callback)
```

Which evaluates each callback to check it exists (newlines are mine).

Comment: Thanks! Now I see why it's not just ignored.